# How to define for a custom unit a long description

Tags: ios, swift

I try to define my own custom Dimension for pieces.

```
class UnitPiece: Dimension {
    override static func baseUnit() -> UnitPiece {
        return self.pieces 
     }

     static let pieces = UnitPiece(symbol: NSLocalizedString("pcs", comment: "Pieces"), converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 1))
}
```

The question, how could I define a new long symbol ("Piece(s)") for the dimension.

I want to us a `MeasurmentFormatter` for getting the `UnitStyle.long` form if needed.

Example:

```
let pcs = Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitPiece.baseUnit())
print(pcs)

let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
formatter.unitStyle = .long
formatter.numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
print(formatter.string(from: pcs))
```

Similar to pre defined `UnitVolume`. There I can explicit get the `medium`-style or the `long`-style for the symbols.

```
let vol = Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitVolume.gallons)
print(vol)

let myFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
myFormatter.unitStyle = .long
myFormatter.numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
print(myFormatter.string(from: vol))
```

The `code` could be copied to a playground.

Comment: Can you explain little bit more what do you wanna achieve ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
class UnitPiece: Dimension {
  override static func baseUnit() -> UnitPiece {
    return self.pieces
  }

  static let pieces = UnitPiece(symbol: NSLocalizedString("pcs", comment: "Pieces"), converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 1))
  static let pieces2 = UnitPiece(symbol: NSLocalizedString("Piece(s)", comment: "Pieces"), converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 1))
}

let pcs = Measurement<UnitPiece>(value: 10, unit: .pieces2)

let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
formatter.numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
print(formatter.string(from: pcs))
```

I got `10.0 Piece(s)` answer. If you want, can take a look further more, when I get home.

Comment: In Swift 5.5 I find I have to write: override static func baseUnit() -> Self ; return pieces as! Self ; //note the capital S in Self